# pass parameter to CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression

I have a query with 3 CTE's.  I am curious how to pass a parameter into them.  If I declare at the top of the query something to the effect of

declare @prioryear varchar(5)
set @prioryear = '2014'

declare @currentyear varchar(5)
set @prioryear = '2015'

Then how can I pass those variables into the CTE's?  I keep trying to put paren's after the CTE names but nothing seems to want to pass.

Thanks,
Joe

`

```
with paidPrior as (
SELECT DISTINCT des_heapplicationSet.des_PeopleId
FROM         des_heapplicationSet INNER JOIN
                      des_zyearSet ON des_heapplicationSet.des_YearId = des_zyearSet.des_zyearId INNER JOIN
                      des_zapplicationstatusSet ON des_heapplicationSet.des_ApplicationStatusId = des_zapplicationstatusSet.des_zapplicationstatusId

WHERE     (des_zyearSet.des_YearText = '2014') AND (des_zapplicationstatusSet.des_applicationstatustext = 'paid') and des_IsMaster =0
),

allCurrent as (
SELECT DISTINCT des_heapplicationSet.des_PeopleId
FROM         des_heapplicationSet INNER JOIN
                      des_zyearSet ON des_heapplicationSet.des_YearId = des_zyearSet.des_zyearId
WHERE     (des_zyearSet.des_YearText = '2015') and des_IsMaster =0
),

peopleSet as (
select distinct des_PeopleId, MAX(des_ApplicationNumber) as appNum
from des_heapplicationSet
where des_PeopleId in (select * from paidPrior) and des_PeopleId not in (select * from allCurrent)
group by des_PeopleId
)

SELECT     des_zterritorySet.des_TerritoryText, des_hepeopleSet.des_PeopleNumber, des_hepeoplenameSet.des_FirstName, des_hepeoplenameSet.des_LastName, des_headdressmasterSet.des_AddressLine, 
                      des_headdressmasterSet.des_FinalCity, des_headdressmasterSet.des_Zip5, des_headdressmasterSet.des_CountyName, 'WI' as stateOfWi,  des_hepeoplephoneSet.des_PhoneNumber, 
                      des_heapplicationSet.des_EmailAddress
FROM         des_heapplicationSet INNER JOIN
                      des_hepeopleSet ON des_heapplicationSet.des_PeopleId = des_hepeopleSet.des_hepeopleId INNER JOIN
                      des_headdressmasterSet ON des_heapplicationSet.des_MailingAddressId = des_headdressmasterSet.des_headdressmasterId INNER JOIN
                      des_zterritorySet ON des_heapplicationSet.des_TerritoryId = des_zterritorySet.des_zterritoryId INNER JOIN
                      des_hepeoplenameSet ON des_heapplicationSet.des_PeopleNameId = des_hepeoplenameSet.des_hepeoplenameId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      des_hepeoplephoneSet ON des_heapplicationSet.des_PeoplePrimaryPhoneId = des_hepeoplephoneSet.des_hepeoplephoneId
where des_ApplicationNumber in (select appnum from peopleSet) and des_TerritoryText = 'Adams'
order by des_TerritoryText
`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just reference the variable directly? Replace '2015' with @currentyear in the CTE

Comment: as soon as I add the declare statement to the top.  I get a 
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

error

Comment: duh!  Just needed a semi-colon behind the parameters!

Comment: Ah yeah, a lot of the newer syntax requires ; and it's easy to forget - I do it plenty myself :)